# Create a specific structure of array in C++

Tags: arrays, global-variables, structure, constants

I want to create a structure in C++ in which some of its elements are arrays (as the following code). I would like to allow the user to declare the number of variables, i.e., nVar, from the console (like what commented in the main function). This is while C++ forces me to declare a constant and global variable for nVar.

Is there a way to resolve my problem? Many thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int nVar = 50;

struct Particle{
    double ObjVal;
    double BestObjVal;
    double Position[nVar];
    double Velocity[nVar];
    double BestPosition[nVar];
};

int main() {
// int nVar;
// cout << "Enter the number of variables: " << endl;
// cin >> nVar;
...
}
```

Comment: I suppose you want an answer in C++. You must specify it in title, tag and in the body of question so peoples can answer your questions fasters ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

You want to create arrays of dinamic size.

You need pointers.

```
struct Particle{
  double objVal;
  double bestObjVal;
  double* position;
  double* velocity;
  double* bestPosition;
};
```

A pointer is the memory address of a variable of the specific type.
In this example, you point to the position of the first `double` value of an array.

In the body :

```
Particicle p;
...
std::cin >> nVar;
p.velocity = new double[nVar];
```

The code mean : i want `nVar` doubles and save the first position in `velocity`. 
So, `velocity[0]` has address `velocity`, `velocity[1]` has address `velocity + sizeof(double)` and so on...

Look for *C++ array with dynamic size*